# Is it possible to stop plugin execution in MS CRM 2011 silently?

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to stop execution of MS CRM plugins without firing exception?

I want to forbid user action and thus created plugin listing `Pre` event step. My plan it to cancel all further actions after that `Pre` step.

How could I achieve this? Without showing error message, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to stop execution and rollback the changes inside a plugin is to throw an exception (`InvalidPluginExecutionException`)

If the plugin is registered as synchronous the exception will always show the error message and is not possible to hide it.

If the plugin is registered as asynchronous the exception is written to the `AsyncOperation` entity

For more information:

[MSDN - Handle Exceptions in Plug-Ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334685.aspx)

Comment: I never though about it but it makes sense. If the operation is async then the error will be silent. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to stop the execution of all plugins that you own, you could create a `HaltPlugin` entity that contains a single attribute, RequestId.  Then (presumably in your base plugin class) before performing any plugin execution, check to see of the Context.RequestId is in the HaltPluginEntity table, if it is, return without doing anything, else, continue as normal.

This would give you the added benefit of not showing any error to the user, since the plugins technically complete successfully, even though no work is done.

### Edit

As MarioZG mentioned in the comments, it would make more sense to use [shared variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328579.aspx) if you're only concerned about plugins (I'm not sure if they work for async plugins).  If you're concerned about plugins and workflows though, this approach won't work, and you'll need to create some sort of `HaltPlugin` entity.

Comment: It this scenario, I think using [shared variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328579.aspx) will save involving new entity and additional db calls. Just pass variable DoNotExecute or something like this