# Cancel System Job Entity from Plugin

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, crm

I have async plugin. I need to cancel his system job (change satus reason to CANCELLED) if let's say a=1. How can I do it?

```
protected override void ExecutePlugin(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var a = 1;
    if(a == 1)
   {
    //cancel the job
   }

}
```

Try to write me also +- code, if you can, thank you.

Comment: How about throwing exception?

Comment: It causes FAILED, not CANCELLED.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041764/is-it-possible-to-stop-plugin-execution-in-ms-crm-2011-scilently

Comment: Why do you want to cancel the Async plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to cancel asynchronous plugins. From within a plugin you can only end execution with the status success or failed (when an exception is thrown).

Only workflows can be canceled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use return when condition fulfill if method is asynchronous. Like as

```
protected async override Task ExecutePlugin(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    int a = 0; // It's your conditioned value. Here 0 is sample value.
    if(a == 1)
   {
     return;
   }

}
```

But void method could not do this.

Comment: I agree. You should just skip the execution instead of cancelling.